# How to force a field to avoid duplicates?

Tags: hibernate

I have a class with two fields id and city, although I defined the city column as unique but it still accepts duplicates. How can I prevent duplicates?

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long id;
@Column(name="City",unique=true)
private String City;
```

Comment: Check this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546131/using-unique-constraint-on-hibernate-jpa2
This will create unique constraint on database when you export schema

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `unique` property (along with `nullable`, `insertable` and `updatable`) only has meaning if you are using Hibernate to generate out your database schema when you deploy. You have to modify your underlying database and add a unique constraint on that column. That way when you try to insert a duplicate record into that table, you will get a `ConstraintViolationException`

Comment: Shameless self-plug: Have a look at the [Hibernate Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257449/how-do-i-use-annotations-to-define-x-relationship-in-hibernate-4-and-spring) that I wrote to help new users get accustomed to Hibernate