# @unique constraint with database support in hibernate

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I have a spring project and want to enforce uniqueness in the database on a field and get the error message back to the UI.

I have read [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546131/using-unique-constraint-on-hibernate-jpa2) and it makes sense so @Column(unique = true) makes the constraint on the table but doesn't enforce it.

So the question becomes how to create a @Unique annotation that checks with the database and returns a error message into BindingResult on POST handler.

An example would be great.

**UPDATE**

I tried the following way to make a custom validator:

The objects (note I have added @valid to get the validator messages to navigate up to BindingResult)

**Person.java**

```
@Entity
public class Person {
public Person() {}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
// other stuff
@UniqueNid
private BigInteger nid;
```

**EpisodePerson.java**

```
@Entity
public class EpisodePerson {
public EpisodePerson(){};

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@Valid
private Person person;
```

**EpisodeViewModel (DTO)**

```
public class EpisodeViewModel {

@Valid
private Episode episode = new Episode();
@Valid
private List<EpisodePerson> persons = new ArrayList<>();
```

**UniqueNid.java**

```
@Documented
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = UniqueNiaValidator.class)
public @interface UniqueNid {

String message() default "{Duplicate ID}";
Class<?>[] groups() default {};
Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

**UniqueNidValidator.java**

```
public class UniqueNidValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueNid, BigInteger> {
public UniqueNidValidator(){};

private PersonRepository personRepository;

@Autowired
public void setPersonRepository(PersonRepository personRepository) {this.personRepository = personRepository;}

public UniqueNidValidator(PersonRepository personRepository) {
    this.personRepository = personRepository;
}

@Override
public void initialize(UniqueNid constraint) {
}

@Override
public boolean isValid(BigInteger nid, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    return nid != null && personRepository.existsByNid(nid);
}
}
```

**PersonRepository.java**

```
...
    Boolean existsByNid(BigInteger nid);
...
```

**Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })

public class Demo3Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(WebApplicationInitializer.class);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Demo3Application.class, args);
}

@Bean
public javax.validation.Validator localValidatorFactoryBean() {
    return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
}
}
```

When I go to submit a person I get :

**Stack Trace (abbreviated)**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.example.validators.UniqueNidValidator.isValid(UniqueNidValidator.java:31) ~[main/:na]
```

**UPDATE 2**

I have also tried this configuration

```
public class UniqueNidValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueNid, BigInteger> {

    public UniqueNidValidator(){};

    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    public UniqueNidValidator(PersonRepository personRepository) {
        this.personRepository = personRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(UniqueNid constraint) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(BigInteger nid, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        System.out.println("About to check " +nid.toString());
        System.out.println("person repo " +personRepository.toString() );
        return personRepository.existsByNid(nid);
    }
}
```

which gives:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.example.validators.UniqueNiaValidator.isValid(UniqueNiaValidator.java:29) ~[main/:na]
```

When I try to print the repo to console.

Comment: What code is exactly on line 31? Looks like `personRepository` wasn't injected and hence it's `null` now. Try to find out why it happens.

Comment: Also why do you create `LocalValidatorFactoryBean`? Why not let the Spring to bootstrap it for you?

Comment: ln31: return nid != null && personRepository.existsByNid(nid); which if I step through the code when testing evaluates (correctly) to true.

Comment: I think the answer may be in this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24955817/jsr303-custom-validators-being-called-twice

Comment: In this case, one way to fix this would be to split entity and dto.

Comment: @SlavaSemushin what do you mean by split entity and DTO?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to [create a custom validation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html#validator-customconstraints) that checks the database. For the database check you can obviously use the probably already existing Spring Data Repository and it's `exists()` method.

A custom validation consists of an annotation to mark the fields to be checked and a class implementing the actual check.

On minor challenge is that the class needs a default constructor and doesn't really support injecting dependencies. So anything you need, you have to basically access from some static reference, including e.g. the repository. So you probably have a separate bean which puts the repository into that static reference.

Such a bean that "catches" a repository and makes it available in a static variable might look like this.

```
@Component
public class RepositoryCatcher{
    public static MyRepository;
    public RepositoryCatcher(MyRepository r){
        repository = r;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks - I have added code - can you be a little more specific? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the exception you mentioned it seems that the only possible NullPointerException is when the `personRepository` is incorrectly injected to the validator.

Please give a try to the solution below:

1. Remove the following bean from your `Demo3Application` and let Spring Boot create the default one instead.

   ```
   @Bean
   public javax.validation.Validator localValidatorFactoryBean() {
       return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
   }
   ```
2. Remove the setter for the repository from the validator but leave the dependency in the constructor as it is right now.

   ```
   @Autowired
   public void setPersonRepository(PersonRepository personRepository {
       this.personRepository = personRepository;
   }
   ```

It's not entirely true that custom validators require a default constructor as mentioned by Jens in his answer. Spring will inject dependencies based on the constructor even though a validator isn't mark as a managed component. The `@Autowired` annotation is also redundant.

In addition, you probably made a mistake in the condition. You should check if a person doesn't exist (Notice the ! mark in the second part).

```
return nid != null && !personRepository.existsByNid(nid);
```

I encourage you to look into [a blog post which addresses your issue](http://dolszewski.com/spring/custom-validation-annotation-in-spring/). Sample code is available in the GitHub repository. You can run, test it, and then compare with your solution.

Comment: I am using a DTO and have UniqueNid on person.nid in the class but also @valid in the DTO on person. Is this a issue too?

Comment: You should have only one in the class that you really want to validate.

Answer (score 0):

This is the validator that worked and errors into BindingResult:

**UniqueNidValidator.java**

```
public class UniqueNiaValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueNid, BigInteger> {

public UniqueNiaValidator(){};

@Autowired
private PersonRepository personRepository;

public UniqueNiaValidator(PersonRepository personRepository) {
    this.personRepository = personRepository;
}

@Override
public void initialize(UniqueNid constraint) {
}

@Override
public boolean isValid(BigInteger nid, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    return !personRepository.existsByNid(nid);
}
}
```

Note the !personRepository.existByNid(nid);

Further more the reason that the repo was blank the second time around was because it was getting called twice as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24955817/jsr303-custom-validators-being-called-twice)

But checking for RDBMS constraint violations on Beans probably isn't a good idea anyway.