# Java Spring how to use Collection as Foreign Key

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I hava to entities with One to Many relationship, how to use Set as a foreign key. 
**Country.java**

```
package hello.world.entity;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="country")
public class Country {
    @Id
    @Column(name="code", length=3, nullable=false)
    private String code;

    @Column(name="name", length=256, nullable=false)
    private String name;
}
```

**CountryLanguage.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="country_language")
public class CountryLanguage {
    @Id
    private int id; // column Id desnt exist on table

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity=Country.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="code")
    private Set<Country> countryCode = new HashSet<>();

    @Column(name="language", length=256, nullable=false)
    private String language;
```

How can use CountryLanguageRepository to **getData by Country code**

I have like this right now

```
@Repository
public interface CountryLanguageRepository extends JpaRepository<CountryLanguage, String> {

    Set<CountryLanguage> findOneByCountryCode(String code);

}
```

Table CountryLanguage doesnt have an ID, but hibernate ask to add it. I have an Exception

`column "id" contains null values`

I have a key on table CountryLanguage (code,language)

Comment: @ScaryWombat why?

Comment: Shouldn't one country have many Languages?  Oh maybe both is good

Comment: @ScaryWombat aaww sorry, yes one country many languages

Comment: well in that case, it is not reversed?

Comment: @ScaryWombat yes, but I have another exception now

Comment: I think that Hibernate requires that all entities have a unique ID - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546131/using-unique-constraint-on-hibernate-jpa2/5677533

Comment: @ScaryWombat can I have primary key on 2 columns as unique keys?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I can use EmbeddedId with OneToOne, it will be a key. Right? Will it work like that?